# PHP Array Combine and Sum

Tags: php, arrays

I have multiple arrays, that get generated when a for loop completes. Now I need to get the total of all these arrays together, but in order, for instance:

```
array1(2, 4, 6, 8, 10)
array2(2, 4, 6, 8, 10)
```

I need to add the 2's together, the 4's etc etc

Then put them into another array.

Some combination of `array_combine` and `array_sum` seems to be the solution but I can't figure it out.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this without any php function except count,

```
$limit = count($array1);
for ($i = 0; $i < $limit; $i++) {
    $array_res[$i] = $array1[$i] + $array2[$i];
```

should work. This will combine your two arrays and add them in the same order. But be sure you used [sort](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.sort.php) or [ksort](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.ksort.php) on both of your arrays before if you're not sure they are in the same order.

Answer (score 0):

1st stlye

```
$a1 = array(
     "a" => 2
    ,"b" => 0
    ,"c" => 5
);

$a2 = array(
     "a" => 3
    ,"b" => 9
    ,"c" => 7
    ,"d" => 10
);

$a3 = array_merge($a1, $a2);
print_r($a3);
```

2nd style

```
$a3 = $a1;

foreach($a2 as $k=>$v) {
    if(array_key_exists($k,$a3))
       $a3[$k] + = $v;
    else
       $a3[$k] = $v; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`array_map()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$arr1 = array(2, 4, 6, 8, 10);
$arr2 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

$arr3 = array_map(
    function($foo, $bar){
        return $foo+$bar;
    },
    $arr1, $arr2
);

print_r($arr3); // outputs:

Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 6
    [2] => 9
    [3] => 12
    [4] => 15
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
$a = array(2, 4, 6, 8, 10);
$b = array(2, 4, 6, 8, 10);
$c = array_map("test", $a, $b);

function test($a, $b) {
return $a + $b;
}

print_r($c);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question You want sum of all the similar digits in both the array:

```
<?php

$array1= array(2, 4, 6, 8, 10);
$array2=array(2, 4, 6, 8, 10);
$array_sum=array();

foreach($array1 as $key1=>$val1)
{
    $sum=0;

    foreach($array2 as $key2 => $val2)
    {
        if($val1==$val2)
        {
            $sum=$sum+$val1;
        }
    }
    $array_sum[]=$sum;
}

print_r($array_sum);

?>
```